# Shamsi date to Gregorian date converter MS Access VBA

Tags: vba

**I have below code to convert Shamsi date to Gregorian but when Gregorian date is "6/8/1900", it convert to Shamsi date "/0/0", could you please help us to resolve this issue to convert till "12/28/1721" date.**

```
Private Month_Name, Spring_Fall
Private Time_Difference, Time_Client
Private Base_Year
Public a, b, c As String

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE As Long = -20
Private Const WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME As Long = &H1


'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    Dim DateFormats()
    Dim CurrentYear()
    Dim MonthNames1(), MonthNames2(), MonthNames3()
    Dim DaysOfMonth1(), DaysOfMonth2(), DaysOfMonth3()
    Dim EmsalKabiseAst As Boolean
    Dim LastKabiseG As Integer 'ÊÇÑíÎ ÂÎÑíä ÓÇá ÞãÑí ßå ßÈíÓå ÔÏå ÇÓÊ'
    Dim TarikheMabna()
    Dim YearNames()
    Dim WeekDays1(), WeekDays2(), WeekDays3()

'--- Farsi Date Convertor --------------------'
 
Private Sub Get_Date(ByVal Days, sal, Mah, Rooz)
   Dim Years, Year_Length
   Do While Days >= 0
     If Kabiseh1(Years) Then
        Year_Length = 366
     Else
        Year_Length = 365
     End If
     If Days - Year_Length >= 0 Then
        Years = Years + 1
        Days = Days - Year_Length
     Else
        sal = Base_Year + Years
        If Days <= 185 Then
           Mah = 1 + (Days \ 31)
           Rooz = 1 + (Days Mod 31)
        Else
           Days = Days - 186
           Mah = 7 + (Days \ 30)
           Rooz = 1 + (Days Mod 30)
        End If
        Exit Sub
     End If
   Loop
End Sub
Private Function Kabiseh1(ByVal Years)
   Dim Temp
   Kabiseh1 = False
   Temp = (Base_Year + Years) - 1309
   If (((Temp Mod 32) - (Temp \ 32)) Mod 4) = 0 Then Kabiseh1 = True
End Function
Public Property Let SFhour(X)
   Spring_Fall = X
End Property
Public Property Let Time_Diff(ByVal t)
   Time_Difference = t
End Property
Public Property Let state(ByVal s)
   Month_Name = s
End Property
Public Function To_Hejri(ByVal what_date, Optional Month_Name)
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
   Dim Days, Day_Name, Day_Number, Temp_Days, Months
   Spring_Fall = False
   If IsMissing(Month_Name) Then Month_Name = 0
 
   Time_Difference = #12:00:00 AM#
   Base_Year = 1332
 
Months = Array(ChrW(1601) & ChrW(1585) & ChrW(1608) & ChrW(1585) & ChrW(1583) & ChrW(1740) & ChrW(1606), ChrW(1575) & ChrW(1585) & ChrW(1583) & ChrW(1740) & ChrW(1576) & ChrW(1588) & ChrW(1607) & ChrW(1578), ChrW(1582) & ChrW(1585) & ChrW(1583) & ChrW(1575) & ChrW(1583), ChrW(1578) & ChrW(1740) & ChrW(1585), ChrW(1605) & ChrW(1585) & ChrW(1583) & ChrW(1575) & ChrW(1583), ChrW(1588) & ChrW(1607) & ChrW(1585) & ChrW(1740) & ChrW(1608) & ChrW(1585), ChrW(1605) & ChrW(1607) & ChrW(1585), ChrW(1570) & ChrW(1576) & ChrW(1575) & ChrW(1606), ChrW(1570) & ChrW(1584) & ChrW(1585), ChrW(1583) & ChrW(1740), ChrW(1576) & ChrW(1607) & ChrW(1605) & ChrW(1606), ChrW(1570) & ChrW(1587) & ChrW(1601) & ChrW(1606) & ChrW(1583))
 
Day_Name = Array(ChrW(1740) & ChrW(1705) & ChrW(1588) & ChrW(1606) & ChrW(1576) & ChrW(1607), ChrW(1583) & ChrW(1608) & ChrW(1588) & ChrW(1606) & ChrW(1576) & ChrW(1607), ChrW(1587) & ChrW(1607) & " " & ChrW(1588) & ChrW(1606) & ChrW(1576) & ChrW(1607), ChrW(1670) & ChrW(1607) & ChrW(1575) & ChrW(1585) & ChrW(1588) & ChrW(1606) & ChrW(1576) & ChrW(1607), ChrW(1662) & ChrW(1606) & ChrW(1580) & " " & ChrW(1588) & ChrW(1606) & ChrW(1576) & ChrW(1607), ChrW(1580) & ChrW(1605) & ChrW(1593) & ChrW(1607), ChrW(1588) & ChrW(1606) & ChrW(1576) & ChrW(1607))
   
   Days = DateDiff("d", #3/21/1953#, what_date)
   Day_Number = Weekday(what_date)
   Dim Year_Length, sal, Mah, Rooz, temp_date
   If FormatDateTime(what_date + Time_Difference, vbShortDate) <> FormatDateTime(what_date, vbShortDate) Then
      Days = Days + 1
      Day_Number = (Day_Number + 1)
      If Day_Number = 8 Then Day_Number = 1
   End If
   Time_Client = FormatDateTime(what_date + Time_Difference, vbLongTime)
   Call Get_Date(Days, sal, Mah, Rooz)
   If ((Mah >= 1 And Mah <= 6) And Not ((Mah = 1 And Rooz = 1) Or (Mah = 6 And Rooz = 31))) And Spring_Fall = True Then
      If FormatDateTime(what_date + Time_Difference + #1:00:00 AM#, vbShortDate) <> FormatDateTime(what_date + Time_Difference, vbShortDate) Then
         Temp_Days = Days + 1
         Day_Number = (Day_Number + 1)
         If Day_Number = 8 Then Day_Number = 1
      Else
         Temp_Days = Days
      End If
      Time_Client = FormatDateTime(what_date + Time_Difference + #1:00:00 AM#, vbLongTime)
      If Temp_Days <> Days Then
         Days = Temp_Days
         If Rooz = 30 And Mah = 6 Then
            If DateDiff("n", Time_Client, #1:00:00 AM#) <= 60 And DateDiff("n", Time_Client, #1:00:00 AM#) >= 0 Then
               Time_Client = FormatDateTime(what_date + Time_Difference, vbLongTime)
               Days = Days - 1
               If Day_Number = 1 Then
                  Day_Number = 7
               Else
                  Day_Number = Day_Number - 1
               End If
            End If
         End If
         Call Get_Date(Days, sal, Mah, Rooz)
      End If
   End If
   If Month_Name = 0 Then
      If Rooz < 10 Then Rooz = "0" & Rooz
      If Mah < 10 Then Mah = "0" & Mah
      To_Hejri = sal & "/" & Mah & "/" & Rooz
   ElseIf Month_Name = 1 Then
      To_Hejri = Rooz & " " & Months(Mah - 1) & " " & sal
   ElseIf Month_Name = 2 Then
      To_Hejri = Day_Name(Day_Number - 1) & " " & sal & "/" & Mah & "/" & Rooz
   ElseIf Month_Name = 3 Then
      To_Hejri = Day_Name(Day_Number - 1) & "  " & Rooz & "  " & Months(Mah - 1) & "  " & sal
   End If
ErrorHandler:
End Function
Public Function To_Time(what_date)
   Call To_Hejri(what_date)
   To_Time = Time_Client
End Function
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Spring_Fall = False
   Month_Name = 0
   Time_Difference = #12:00:00 AM#
   Base_Year = 1332
End Sub



Public Static Function Shamsi() As Long
'Çíä ÊÇÈÚ ÊÇÑíÎ ÌÇÑí ÓíÓÊã ÑÇ Èå ÊÇÑíÎ åÌÑí ÔãÓí ÊÈÏíá ãí ßäÏ
Dim Shamsi_Mabna As Long
Dim Miladi_mabna As Date
Dim Dif As Long
'ÏÑ ÇíäÌÇ 78/10/11 ÈÇ 2000/01/01 ãÚÇÏá ÞÑÇÑÏÇÏå ÔÏå
Shamsi_Mabna = 13411011
Miladi_mabna = #1/1/1963#
Dif = DateDiff("d", Miladi_mabna, Date)
If Dif < 0 Then
MsgBox "ÊÇÑíÎ ÌÇÑí ÓíÓÊã ÔãÇ äÇÏÑÓÊ ÇÓÊ , ÂäÑÇ ÇÕáÇÍ ßäíÏ."
Else
Shamsi = AddDay(Shamsi_Mabna, Dif)
End If
End Function

Public Function dat() As String
' ÈßÇÑ ÈÈÑíÏ Now() ÑÇ ãí ÊæÇäíÏ ÏÑ ÒÇÑÔÇÊ ÈÌÇí ÊÇÈÚ Dat() ÊÇÈÚ
dat = DayWeek(Shamsi) & " - " & Slash(Shamsi)
End Function

Public Function Slash(f_date As Variant) As String
' Çíä ÊÇÈÚ íß ÊÇÑíÎ ÑÇ ÏÑíÇÝÊ æ ÈÕæÑÊ íß ÑÔÊå 10 ÑÞãí ÔÇãá / æ åÇÑ ÑÞã ÈÑÇí ÓÇá ÈÇÒãíÑÏÇäÏ
f_date = Replace(f_date, "/", "")
Dim a As Long
a = CLng(f_date)
Slash = Format(sal(a), "0000") & "/" & Format(Mah(a), "00") & "/" & Format(Rooz(a), "00")
End Function
Public Function NoSlash(f_date As Variant) As String
' Çíä ÊÇÈÚ íß ÊÇÑíÎ ÑÇ ÏÑíÇÝÊ æ ÈÕæÑÊ íß ÑÔÊå 10 ÑÞãí ÔÇãá / æ åÇÑ ÑÞã ÈÑÇí ÓÇá ÈÇÒãíÑÏÇäÏ
NoSlash = Replace(f_date, "/", "")
End Function

Function ValidDate(f_date As Variant) As Boolean
' Çíä ÊÇÈÚ ÇÚÊÈÇÑ íß ÚÏÏ æÑæÏí ÑÇ ÇÒ äÙÑ ÊÇÑíÎ åÌÑí ÔãÓí ÈÑÑÓí ãí ßäÏ
' ÑÇ ÈÑãí ÑÏÇäÏ False æÇÑ äÇãÚÊÈÑ ÈÇÔÏ True ÇÑ ÊÇÑíÎ ãÚÊÈÑ ÈÇÔÏ
On Error GoTo Err_ValidDate
'>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Dim M, s, R As Byte
f_date = Replace(f_date, "/", "")
R = Rooz(CLng(f_date))
M = Mah(CLng(f_date))
s = sal(CLng(f_date))
If f_date < 10000101 Then Exit Function
If M > 12 Or M = 0 Or R = 0 Then Exit Function
If R > MahDays(s, M) Then Exit Function
ValidDate = True

Exit_ValidDate:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
Err_ValidDate:
    Select Case err.Number
        Case 0
            Resume Exit_ValidDate:
        Case 94
            ValidDate = True
        Case Else
            MsgBox err.Number & " " & err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error in module Module2 - function ValidDate"
            Resume Exit_ValidDate:
    End Select
End Function

Public Function AddDay(ByVal f_date As Variant, ByVal add As Long) As Long
    'Çíä ÊÇÈÚ ÊÚÏÇÏ ÑæÒ ÏáÎæÇå ÑÇ Èå ÊÇÑíÎ ÑæÒ ÇÖÇÝå ãíßäÏ
    On Error GoTo Err_AddDay
    '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    f_date = Replace(f_date, "/", "")
    Dim K, M, R, Days As Byte
    Dim s As Integer
    R = Rooz(CLng(f_date))
    M = Mah(CLng(f_date))
    s = sal(CLng(f_date))
    K = Kabiseh(s)
    'ÊÈÏíá ÑæÒ Èå ÚÏÏ 1 ÌåÊ ÇÏÇãå ãÍÇÓÈÇÊ æ íÇ ÇÊãÇã ãÍÇÓÈå
    Days = MahDays(s, M)
    If add > Days - R Then
        add = add - (Days - R + 1)
        R = 1
        If M < 12 Then
            M = M + 1
        Else
            M = 1
            s = s + 1
        End If
    Else
        R = R + add
        add = 0
    End If
    While add > 0
        K = Kabiseh(s) 'ßÈíÓå: 1 æ ÛíÑ ßÈíÓå: 0
        Days = MahDays(s, M) 'ÊÚÏÇÏ ÑæÒåÇí ãÇå ÝÚáí
        Select Case add
            Case Is < Days
                'ÇÑ ÊÚÏÇÏ ÑæÒåÇí ÇÝÒæÏäí ßãÊÑ ÇÒ íß ãÇå ÈÇÔÏ
                R = R + add
                add = 0
            Case Days To IIf(K = 0, 365, 366) - 1
                'ÇÑ ÊÚÏÇÏ ÑæÒåÇí ÇÝÒæÏäí ÈíÔÊÑ ÇÒ íß ãÇå æ ßãÊÑ ÇÒ íß ÓÇá ÈÇÔÏ
                add = add - Days
                If M < 12 Then
                    M = M + 1
                Else
                    s = s + 1
                    M = 1
                End If
            Case Else
                'ÇÑ ÊÚÏÇÏ ÑæÒåÇí ÇÝÒæÏäí ÈíÔÊÑ ÇÒ íß ÓÇá ÈÇÔÏ
                s = s + 1
                add = add - IIf(K = 0, 365, 366)
        End Select
    Wend
    AddDay = CLng(s & Format(M, "00") & Format(R, "00"))

Exit_AddDay:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
Err_AddDay:
    Select Case err.Number
        Case 0
            Resume Exit_AddDay:
        Case 94
            AddDay = 0
        Case Else
            MsgBox err.Number & " " & err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error in module Module2 - function AddDay"
            Resume Exit_AddDay:
    End Select
End Function
.
.
'
Public Function MiladiToShamsi(mtsYear, mtsMonth, mtsDay) As String
' Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ íß ÊÇÑíÎ ãíáÇÏí ÑÇ ÑÝÊå Èå ÔãÓí ÊÈÏíá ãí ßäÏ

    Call SetVariables
    Dim mtsDateDiff As Long
    Dim mtsDate
    If mtsYear < 620 Then
        MiladiToShamsi = ""
        Exit Function

    End If
    mtsDate = mtsMonth & "/" & mtsDay & "/" & mtsYear


    mtsDateDiff = DateDiff("d", TarikheMabna(0), mtsDate)
    '285615
    MiladiToShamsi = AddToShamsi(1385, 10, 7, mtsDateDiff)





End Function

Public Function MiladiToGhamari(mtgYear, mtgMonth, mtgDay) As String
' Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ íß ÊÇÑíÎ ãíáÇÏí ÑÇ ÑÝÊå Èå ÞãÑí ÊÈÏíá ãí ßäÏ
    
    Call SetVariables
    Dim mtgDateDiff As Long
    Dim mtgDate
    
    If mtgYear < 570 Then
        MiladiToGhamari = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    mtgDate = mtgMonth & "/" & mtgDay & "/" & mtgYear
    
    
    mtgDateDiff = DateDiff("d", TarikheMabna(0), mtgDate)
    
    MiladiToGhamari = AddToGhamari(1427, 12, 7, mtgDateDiff)
    MiladiToGhamari = Format(MiladiToGhamari, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    Debug.Print ""
    
    
    
    
    
End Function

Public Function NextDayShamsi(ndDate) As String
    'Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ íß ÊÇÑíÎ ÔãÓí ÑÇ ÑÝÊå æ ÊÇÑíÎ íß ÑæÒ ÈÚÏ ÑÇ Èå ãÇ ãí ÏåÏ
   ' ÝÑãÊ ÊÇÑíÎí ßå Èå Çíä ÊÇÈÚ ÏÇÏå ãí ÔæÏ ÈÇíÏ Èå ÕæÑÊ ÒíÑ ÈÇÔÏ
   ' Y/M/D (Ex: 1385/9/23)
   
   Dim ndDaysOfMonths()
   Dim ndP() As String
   Dim ndP2()
   
   ndP = Split(ndDate, "/")
   'Debug.Print ndP(0) & "," & ndP(1) & "," & ndP(2)
   ndP2 = Array(Val(ndP(0)), Val(ndP(1)), Val(ndP(2)))
   
   
   
   
   ndDaysOfMonths = DaysOfMonth2
   
   'Debug.Print ndDate
   
   If IsKabiseShamsi(ndP2(0)) Then
        ndDaysOfMonths(11) = 30
    Else
        ndDaysOfMonths(11) = 29
    
   End If
   
   If ndP2(1) = 12 And ndP2(2) = ndDaysOfMonths(11) Then
        NextDayShamsi = (ndP2(0) + 1) & "/" & 1 & "/" & 1
    ElseIf ndP2(1) < 12 And ndP2(2) = (ndDaysOfMonths(ndP2(1) - 1)) Then
        NextDayShamsi = ndP2(0) & "/" & (ndP2(1) + 1) & "/" & 1
    Else
       NextDayShamsi = ndP2(0) & "/" & ndP2(1) & "/" & (ndP2(2) + 1)
       
    
    
   End If
   NextDayShamsi = Format(NextDayShamsi, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    
End Function

Public Function NextDayGhamari(ndgDate) As String
    'Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ íß ÊÇÑíÎ ÞãÑí ÑÇ ÑÝÊå æ ÊÇÑíÎ íß ÑæÒ ÈÚÏ ÑÇ Èå ãÇ ãí ÏåÏ
   ' ÝÑãÊ ÊÇÑíÎí ßå Èå Çíä ÊÇÈÚ ÏÇÏå ãí ÔæÏ ÈÇíÏ Èå ÕæÑÊ ÒíÑ ÈÇÔÏ
   ' Y-M-D (Ex: 1385-9-23)
   
   Dim ndgDaysOfMonths()
   Dim ndgP() As String
   Dim ndgP2()
   
   ndgP = Split(ndgDate, "/")
   'Debug.Print ndP(0) & "," & ndP(1) & "," & ndP(2)
   ndgP2 = Array(Val(ndgP(0)), Val(ndgP(1)), Val(ndgP(2)))
   
   
   
   
   ndgDaysOfMonths = DaysOfMonth3
   
   'Debug.Print ndDate
   
   If IsKabiseGhamari(ndgP2(0)) Then
        ndgDaysOfMonths(11) = 30
    Else
        ndgDaysOfMonths(11) = 29
    
   End If
   
   If ndgP2(1) = 12 And ndgP2(2) = ndgDaysOfMonths(11) Then
        NextDayGhamari = (ndgP2(0) + 1) & "/" & 1 & "/" & 1
    ElseIf ndgP2(1) < 12 And ndgP2(2) = (ndgDaysOfMonths(ndgP2(1) - 1)) Then
        NextDayGhamari = ndgP2(0) & "/" & (ndgP2(1) + 1) & "/" & 1
    Else
       NextDayGhamari = ndgP2(0) & "/" & ndgP2(1) & "/" & (ndgP2(2) + 1)
       
    
    
   End If
   NextDayGhamari = Format(NextDayGhamari, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    
End Function


Public Function PrevDayShamsi(pdDate) As String
    'Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ íß ÊÇÑíÎ ÔãÓí ÑÇ ÑÝÊå æ ÊÇÑíÎ íß ÑæÒ ÞÈá ÑÇ Èå ãÇ ãí ÏåÏ
   ' ÝÑãÊ ÊÇÑíÎí ßå Èå Çíä ÊÇÈÚ ÏÇÏå ãí ÔæÏ ÈÇíÏ Èå ÕæÑÊ ÒíÑ ÈÇÔÏ
   ' Y-M-D (Ex: 1385-9-23)
   
   Dim pdDaysOfMonths()
   Dim pdP() As String
   Dim pdP2()
   
   pdP = Split(pdDate, "/")
   'Debug.Print ndP(0) & "," & ndP(1) & "," & ndP(2)
   pdP2 = Array(Val(pdP(0)), Val(pdP(1)), Val(pdP(2)))
   
   
   
   
   pdDaysOfMonths = DaysOfMonth2
   
   'Debug.Print ndDate
   
   If IsKabiseShamsi(pdP2(0)) Then
        pdDaysOfMonths(11) = 30
    Else
        pdDaysOfMonths(11) = 29
    
   End If
   
   If pdP2(1) = 1 And pdP2(2) = 1 Then
   Dim n As Integer
        n = pdP2(0) - 1
        If IsKabiseShamsi(n) Then
            PrevDayShamsi = (pdP2(0) - 1) & "/" & 12 & "/" & 30
        Else
            PrevDayShamsi = (pdP2(0) - 1) & "/" & 12 & "/" & 29
        End If
    ElseIf pdP2(1) > 1 And pdP2(2) = 1 Then
        PrevDayShamsi = pdP2(0) & "/" & (pdP2(1) - 1) & "/" & (pdDaysOfMonths((pdP2(1) - 2)))
    Else
       PrevDayShamsi = pdP2(0) & "/" & pdP2(1) & "/" & (pdP2(2) - 1)
       
    
    
   End If
   
    PrevDayShamsi = Format(PrevDayShamsi, "yyyy/mm/dd")
End Function



Public Function PrevDayGhamari(pdgDate) As String
    'Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ íß ÊÇÑíÎ ÞãÑí ÑÇ ÑÝÊå æ ÊÇÑíÎ íß ÑæÒ ÞÈá ÑÇ Èå ãÇ ãí ÏåÏ
   ' ÝÑãÊ ÊÇÑíÎí ßå Èå Çíä ÊÇÈÚ ÏÇÏå ãí ÔæÏ ÈÇíÏ Èå ÕæÑÊ ÒíÑ ÈÇÔÏ
   ' Y-M-D (Ex: 1385-9-23)
   
   Dim pdgDaysOfMonths()
   Dim pdgP() As String
   Dim pdgP2()
   
   pdgP = Split(pdgDate, "/")
   'Debug.Print ndP(0) & "," & ndP(1) & "," & ndP(2)
   pdgP2 = Array(Val(pdgP(0)), Val(pdgP(1)), Val(pdgP(2)))
   
   
   
   
   pdgDaysOfMonths = DaysOfMonth3
   
   'Debug.Print ndDate
   
   If IsKabiseGhamari(pdgP2(0)) Then
        pdgDaysOfMonths(11) = 30
    Else
        pdgDaysOfMonths(11) = 29
    
   End If
   
   If pdgP2(1) = 1 And pdgP2(2) = 1 Then
   Dim n As Integer
        n = pdgP2(0) - 1
        If IsKabiseGhamari(n) Then
            PrevDayGhamari = (pdgP2(0) - 1) & "/" & 12 & "/" & 30
        Else
            PrevDayGhamari = (pdgP2(0) - 1) & "/" & 12 & "/" & 29
        End If
    ElseIf pdgP2(1) > 1 And pdgP2(2) = 1 Then
        PrevDayGhamari = pdgP2(0) & "/" & (pdgP2(1) - 1) & "/" & (pdgDaysOfMonths((pdgP2(1) - 2)))
    Else
       PrevDayGhamari = pdgP2(0) & "/" & pdgP2(1) & "/" & (pdgP2(2) - 1)
       
    
    
   End If
   PrevDayGhamari = Format(PrevDayGhamari, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    
End Function
Private Sub SetVariables()
    DateFormats = Array("ãíáÇÏí", "ÔãÓí", "ÞãÑí")
    CurrentYear = Array(2006, 1385, 1427)
    TarikheMabna = Array("12/28/2006", "1385-10-7", "1427-12-7")
    YearNames = Array("ãÇÑ", "ÇÓÈ", "æÓÝäÏ", "ãíãæä", "ãÑÛ", "Ó", "Îæß", "ãæÔ", "Çæ", "áä", "ÎÑæÔ", "äåä")
    WeekDays1 = Array("Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday")
    WeekDays2 = Array("ÔäÈå", "íßÔäÈå", "ÏæÔäÈå", "Óå ÔäÈå", "åÇÑÔäÈå", "äÌ ÔäÈå", "ÌãÚå")
    WeekDays3 = Array("ÇáÓÈÊ", "ÇáÇÍÏ", "ÇáÇËäíä", "ÇáËáÇËÇÁ", "ÇáÇÑÈÚÇÁ", "ÇáÎãíÓ", "ÇáÌãÚå")
    
    'Taghvim-e Miladi
    MonthNames1 = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    DaysOfMonth1 = Array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)

    'Taghvim-e Shamsi
    MonthNames2 = Array("ÝÑæÑÏíä", "ÇÑÏíÈåÔÊ", "ÎÑÏÇÏ", "ÊíÑ", "ãÑÏÇÏ", "ÔåÑíæÑ", "ãåÑ", "ÂÈÇä", "ÂÐÑ", "Ïí", "Èåãä", "ÇÓÝäÏ")
    DaysOfMonth2 = Array(31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29)
    
    'Taghvim-e Ghamari
    MonthNames3 = Array("ãÍÑã", "ÕÝÑ", "ÑÈíÚ ÇáÇæá", "ÑÈíÚ ÇáËÇäí", "ÌãÇÏí ÇáÇæá", "ÌãÇÏí ÇáËÇäí", "ÑÌÈ", "ÔÚÈÇä", "ÑãÖÇä", "ÔæÇá", "ÐæÇáÞÚÏå", "ÐæÇáÍÌå")
    DaysOfMonth3 = Array(30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29)
End Sub

Public Function ShamsiToGhamari(stgYear, stgMonth, stgDay) As String
' Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ íß ÊÇÑíÎ ÔãÓí ÑÇ Èå ÞãÑí ÊÈÏíá ãí äãÇíÏ

    Call SetVariables
    Dim stgDateDiff As Long
    Dim stgDate2, stgYear2, stgMonth2, stgDay2
    
    
    stgDateDiff = DateDifShamsi(1385, 10, 7, stgYear, stgMonth, stgDay)
    stgDate2 = AddToGhamari(1427, 12, 7, stgDateDiff)
     
    ShamsiToGhamari = stgDate2
    
    ShamsiToGhamari = Format(ShamsiToGhamari, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    
    
End Function

Public Function ShamsiToMiladi(stmYear, stmMonth, stmDay) As String
' Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ ÊÇÑíÎ åÇí ÔãÓí ÑÇ Èå ãíáÇÏí ÊÈÏíá ãí ßäÏ
    Call SetVariables
   
    Dim stmDateDiff As Long
    Dim stmDate2, stmYear2, stmMonth2, stmDay2
    
    
    stmDateDiff = DateDifShamsi(1385, 10, 7, stmYear, stmMonth, stmDay)
    stmDate2 = DateAdd("d", stmDateDiff, "12/28/2006") 'DateTime.DateSerial(2006, 12, 28 + stmDateDiff)
    stmYear2 = Year(stmDate2)
    stmMonth2 = Month(stmDate2)
    stmDay2 = Day(stmDate2)
    
    ShamsiToMiladi = stmYear2 & "/" & stmMonth2 & "/" & stmDay2
    
    ShamsiToMiladi = Format(ShamsiToMiladi, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    
End Function

Public Function GhamariToMiladi(gtmYear, gtmMonth, gtmDay) As String
' Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ ÊÇÑíÎ åÇí ÞãÑí ÑÇ Èå ãíáÇÏí ÊÈÏíá ãí ßäÏ
   If gtmYear = "" Or gtmMonth = "" Or gtmDay = "" Then
        GhamariToMiladi = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    Call SetVariables
    Dim gtmDateDiff As Long
    Dim gtmDate2, gtmYear2, gtmMonth2, gtmDay2
    
    
    gtmDateDiff = DateDifGhamari(1427, 12, 7, gtmYear, gtmMonth, gtmDay)
    gtmDate2 = DateAdd("d", gtmDateDiff, "12/28/2006") 'DateTime.DateSerial(2006, 12, 28 + stmDateDiff)
    gtmYear2 = Year(gtmDate2)
    gtmMonth2 = Month(gtmDate2)
    gtmDay2 = Day(gtmDate2)
    
    GhamariToMiladi = gtmYear2 & "/" & gtmMonth2 & "/" & gtmDay2
    GhamariToMiladi = Format(GhamariToMiladi, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    
    
End Function


Public Function GhamariToShamsi(gtsYear, gtsMonth, gtsDay) As String
' Çíä ÊÇÈÚ¡ ÊÇÑíÎ åÇí ÞãÑí ÑÇ Èå ÔãÓí ÊÈÏíá ãí ßäÏ
   If gtsYear = "" Or gtsMonth = "" Or gtsDay = "" Then
        GhamariToShamsi = ""
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    
    Call SetVariables
    Dim gtsDateDiff As Long
    Dim gtsDate2, gtsYear2, gtsMonth2, gtsDay2
    
    
    gtsDateDiff = DateDifGhamari(1427, 12, 7, gtsYear, gtsMonth, gtsDay)
    '151292
    
    gtsDate2 = AddToShamsi(1385, 10, 7, gtsDateDiff)
    GhamariToShamsi = gtsDate2
    GhamariToShamsi = Format(GhamariToShamsi, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    
End Function
```

I want to convert Shamsi date to Gregorian but when Gregorian date is this date '6/8/1900' it convert to Shamsi this date '/0/0', it accept to convert only 70 years previous but less then 70 year it doesn't convert, could you please help us to solve this issue in attached code to convert till 12/28/1721 date. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies Masoom for the Community Bot, it is perfectly obvious what you need!

Comment: Welcome Massom! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Its ok no problem.